# Print the only path between two given vertex in given graph

Tags: graph, depth-first-search

A tree shaped `n` vertex connected by `n-1` edge.. Then i have to find total cost from (a to b edge) as per query. Each edge has given specific cost. I am trying to do it using dfs. But I'm getting tle. Has someone better approach. 

Please suggest some better approach. Special thanks for them!

Comment: _DFS is a distributed filesystem from Microsoft. Note: for questions about depth-first search, please use the depth-first-search tag. **NOT to be confused** with [depth-first-search]_

Answer (score 1):

Root the tree arbitrarily and precompute distance from the root to each node. Then for each query `(a,b)` compute the [lowest common ancestor](https://www.hackerrank.com/topics/lowest-common-ancestor) of `a` and `b` (call it `c`), and then the the distance between the two will be (with `dist[i]` representing distance from the root) `dist[a]+dist[b]-2*dist[c]`. The distance precomputation runs in `O(N)`, LCA precomputation in `O(NlogN)` and each individual query can run in `O(logN)` (depending on implementation).

There are many resources online concerning this problem, so feel free to google some more if the Hackerrank page I linked is insufficient.

Comment: Thanks for ur guidelines. I will check out other sites if got further problems.